# DES - encrypt 3 times - DES(DES(DES, k), k'), k) - stronger than 2DES with 2 different keys?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, block-cipher, des, 3des

What if were to use DES in the following way:

For a given plaintext `x` and key `k` we will perform: `DES(DES(DES, k), k'), k)`, where `k'` is the complementary of `k`.

If an adversary has a small amount of text and their ciphertexts, would he still have to run 3 * 2^56 encryptions: for each key perform `DES(DES(DES, k), k'), k)` and therefore this encryption is stronger than 2DES with 2 keys (meet in the middle requires 2^57 runs) but less than real 3DES which is much more than 2^57 ?

Or is there a smarter way ?

Comment: Does [Effective key length of Two-Key Triple-DES](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33066/effective-key-length-of-two-key-triple-des) help you?

Comment: and this? [How can I attack a Triple-Block cipher with 2 keys (like 3DES) with a cost of ≤ 2⁵⁶](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42362/how-can-i-attack-a-triple-block-cipher-with-2-keys-like-3des-with-a-cost-of-%E2%89%A4)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments two key triple DES (without your complementary key condition) already has efficient attacks against it, going back to the 80's. See for example a detailed analysis in Van Oorschot and Wiener [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=3615D5061559F54AB55B39B17A50A825?doi=10.1.1.66.6575&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which converts a chosen plaintext attack by Merkle and Hellman to a known plaintext attack.

Since 2 key 3DES is already weak, trying for sophisticated and complicated improvements based on the complementary key condition is likely not worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Let assume that running a **single DES** key search operation requires 1 key schedule, encryption, and 1 comparison that now we omit.

```
for key in 2^56
    k = key_schedule(key)  //note to distingush the key schedule has a funtion
    test (E(k,m), c)
```

**Your 3DES** requires3 encryptions, only 2 schedule runs if we want to attack brute-force. The key space is still $2^{56}$ since we don't need a sperate key search for the complement $k'$, just complement the current key and run the key schedule.

```
for k in 2^56
   k1 = key_schedule(k)
   k2 = key_schedule(k')
   test ( E(E(E(m,k1),k2),k1), c)
```

So in, the total we need at most 3-times single DES operations and 2-times DES key schedules. If we assume that the running time of the key schedule and the encryption are same, then your 3DES is $5/2=2.5$ slower than brute-forcing a single DES.

---

Now, turn into 2DES with two different keys. In the complexity calculations of the [meet-in-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack) the big $\mathcal{O}$ notation hides some details;

1. A memory for a table requirement for storing the encryption with each key; we need to store $6\cdot 2 \cdot  2^{56}$-byte $\approx 1152$ PetaByte. This is still very huge amount to store and process. Google has  15 exabytes = 15000 petabytes.
2. Sorting the table $n \log n$ step, therefor we have $ 56 \cdot 2^{56}$
3. Searching within the table $56$ steps by binary search.

When these values are added <sup>1</sup>, **3DES search will be faster** than the 2DES, and can be calculated by using in quite reasonable time if you can access the [Titan](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/olcf-resources/compute-systems/titan/), you can brute-force in couple hours. The Titan that can reach $2^{60}$ every [easily](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63537/61539).

---

<sup>1</sup> I would like to note here that, DES encryption and sorting cannot be directly compared. A deeper calculation is required.

Comment: Let me help you over that 3k border :)